# create a new face based on a edge

Tags: modeling

I want to achieve the bases of arches (like at the foreground).
I linked vertices with edges (in red)  but I don't kwow how to create new faces based on the edges (before  extruding...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an answer.

I used Edit Mode > Face select > Mesh > Bisect.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct. This is an easy way you can tackle the modeling you want to do here. I included a gif to show the process, or you can do the following.

You can insert a loop cut by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> . 
Then to create an extrusion, loop select the polygons with alt clicking on the edge of the loop. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>  to enter the extrude menu and choose either extrude along normals or extrude individual faces.

[image: Blender - Loopcut CTRL + R]